# Php switch not updating variable

Tags: php, variables, scope, switch-statement

I have a variable `$someVar` which get's included inside `$test` and should change it's value upon different cases. The problem is that the `$someVar` does not get updated inside a switch statement. Here is my code:

```
<?php
    $someVar = '';
    $test = '<div class="test">This is ' . $someVar . '</div>';
    $param = 1;
    switch ($param) 
    {
        case ($param == 1):
            $someVar = 'some text';
            echo $test;
        break;
    };
?>
```

This always outputs an empty `$someVar` and echoes `This is` instead of `This is some text`. I'm guessing that it's an scope issue so any help appreciated, thanks.

Comment: It's because $someVar was empty initially and assigned to $test with an empty string.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have defined `$test` at that moment when `$someVar` was empty.

```
$someVar = '';
$test = '<div class="test">This is ' . $someVar . '</div>';
```

**Change this to:**

```
<?php
    $someVar = '';
    $test = '<div class="test">This is ' . $someVar . '</div>';
    $param = 1;
    switch ($param) {
        case ($param == 1):
            $someVar = 'some text';
            echo $test;
            break;
    };
?>
```

**This:**

```
<?php

$someVar = '';
$param = 1;
switch ($param)
{
    case 1:
        $someVar = 'some text';
        break;
};
$test = '<div class="test">This is ' . $someVar . '</div>';
echo $test;
?>
```

Comment: @g5wx Welcome ... :)

Answer (score 4):

If you wanted to update $test variable data then you have to update $test variable like below-

```
<?php

$someVar = '';
$param = 1;
switch ($param)
{
     case 1:
        $someVar = 'some text';
        $test = '<div class="test">This is ' . $someVar . '</div>';
        break;
        case 2:
        $someVar = 'some text another';
        $test = '<div class="test">This is ' . $someVar . '</div>';
        break;
};
echo $test;
?>
```

Comment: Yep, i was trying to avoid this way so i can define elements inside $test only once.